# 'parse_date' argument in pd.read_csv() and some issues regarding that are below

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

**Why the output is nan for pounds rows when I remove 'parse_dates = True' from both the read_csv
what 'parse_dates = True' actually working inside I m confused if its columns are multiplying then there would be some values in pounds why every value became NaN i had given links of datsets below...**
https://github.com/johnashu/datacamp/blob/master/sp500.csv
**i cant find exchange.csv bcos i m learning from datacamp and i got one csv and cant find 'exchange.csv' basically it contains float numbers and this is not imp imp is why without parse_date its giving me nan**

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd

# Read 'sp500.csv' into a DataFrame: sp500
sp500 = pd.read_csv('sp500.csv',parse_dates = True, index_col = 'Date')

# Read 'exchange.csv' into a DataFrame: exchange
exchange = pd.read_csv('exchange.csv', parse_dates = True, index_col = 'Date')

# Subset 'Open' & 'Close' columns from sp500: dollars
dollars = sp500[['Open', 'Close']]

# Print the head of dollars
print(dollars.head())

# Convert dollars to pounds: pounds
pounds = dollars.multiply(exchange['GBP/USD'], axis = 'rows')

# Print the head of pounds
print(pounds.head())
```

Comment: Please post the output of `print(dollars.head())` and `print(pounds.head())`. But please don't use an image! See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377517/how-can-i-post-a-question-with-sample-output) for details. Thank You!

Comment: I'm loading your two DataFrames and not running into any issues, FWIW.

Comment: guys my question is very simple I m just saying that wherever in the code I remove 'parse_dates =True' then why the output varies when I write it and not write it, I just want to know what parse_dates=True doing inside my code@MacOS @mechanical_meat

Answer (score 0):

So if the problem is finding echange.csv, I found it: https://github.com/johnashu/datacamp/blob/master/exchange.csv
I got it to work fine with all your code, and I don't understand what you're talking about with `parse_dates`. If you need more information on that function, use the pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html Hope I can help.

Comment: my question is very simple I m just saying that wherever in the code I remove 'parse_dates =True' then why the output varies when I write it and not write it, I just want to know what parse_dates=True doing inside my code

Answer (score 0):

Pandas dataframe multiplies a series by matching index. In `sp500.csv`, the index was `yy-mm-dd`. In `exchange.csv`, the index was `yy/mm/dd`. If you didn't parse_dates, the indices wouldn't match. `parse_dates`made both to be the same format `yy-mm-dd`.